# JSON data not showing the correct information

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm trying to create a function that selects data from database in server-side and sets it as value of textbox in client-side. It works fine in server-side, but in client side, if I alert the data, it shows `[oject Object]`, and for data.id it shows `undefined`, and I can't figure out why. Thanks a lot !

**Server-side:**

```
app.post('/id', function(req,res) {

    var data = req.body;
    var id = data.id;
    console.log(id);
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Control WHERE id=" +id;
    connection.query(query, function(error, result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
    });
});
```

**Client-side:**

```
function select()
            {
                var id = $('#nr_reg').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/id',
                    data : {
                        id: id
                    },

                    success : function(data){           
                        alert(data);                          
                        var id = data.id;
                        $('#optic').val(id);

                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                }); 
            }
```

Comment: what does the response data look like in your browser devtools? You should be able to see the structure there.

Comment: If you `alert` on an object, it will always show `[object]` - use `console.log(data)` or (better) `console.dir(data)`

Comment: its better to go to the documentation and check the docs for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation here is that, the two `data` are different from each other.

```
//input for ajax page
data : {
    id: id
}
```

and

```
//output from ajax page
success:function(data)
```

The first one is the values passed the the `url: '/id'` second one stands for the value returned from the server as a result of the AJAX call.

That means, you can give any name for the function argument like `success:function( value )`.

Comment: If I put value beetwen brackets, it shows `object HTMLInputElement]`.

Comment: @Ezekiel what you are getting in the success function is the return from server.

Comment: All the columns from database in the row with the id: `[ { id: 10,
    data: '',
    kw: '11',
    nr_articol: '279630-99',
    proiect: 'AUHE',
    optic: '2037',
    electric: '',
    reelectric: '',
    smd: 'on',
    scurt_smd: '1',
    incomplete_smd: '',
    bile: '',} ]
`

Comment: @Ezekiel do console.log(data) in the success function, and check in the developer tool console to see the output.

Comment: The return is an array? If yes, the correctly would `var id = data[0].id;`.

Comment: @Ezekiel try what Lucas mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: It says the same thing... `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting those data instead of alert use console.log(data).
and one more thing if you wanna se that you object having that id or not 
just pass those data as JSON.stringify(data).and print those data using console log .and see what it contains.
Then easily you can solve your problem .

Comment: I did this. And it says `undefined`.

Comment: what you did , Be clear means you pass those data like this console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

if your data is coming as Object then this is the way you can check or print in console , what are the fields your object hold.
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
and check in the developer tool console, what you are getting .@Ezekiel

Comment: And if your data is coming as String ,then you have  to form that value as Object using 
var dataObject=JSON.parse(data);
and then use 
var id=dataObject.id;
Hope this will work . @Ezekiel